# Emulate a Raspberry Pi 1 or Zero in QEMU with the peripherals and the memory maps

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, emulation, qemu

Im trying to build a custom bare metal OS for Raspberry Pi 1 and Zero. I want to emulate any of these machines in QEMU but the only supported machines are raspi2 and raspi3.
I need to run it on a raspi1 or zero because I dont want to implement multicore support and in raspi1 and zero everything its easier.

Thanks!